# Float left, right with flexbox while vertical aligned width 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align my 3 items, that the reason why I use

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;     /* center items vertically, in this case */
```

Not sure If it is good to practise, but now that my items are aligned correctly I cant spread the items to the left corner (menu), right corner (about), and the middle (logo). How can I do this?

Are there other alternatives to align items without flex, I have tried a lot and none of them worked so far.

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#moveItem {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.85;
    filter: alpha(opacity=85); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

body, html{
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    overflow-y: hidden;
    background: black;
}

#navigator {

    z-index: 2;

    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;     /* center items vertically, in this case */



}

#navIcon{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor:pointer;


}
.about {
    float: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#navigator a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.logo {
    display: inline;
}

.logo img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
}

.logoheader{
    background:  rgba(0, 0, 0,  0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.logoText {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin-left: -12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigator">
    <div id="navIcon" onclick="openNav()"> &#9776;</div>

    <div class="logoheader">
      <a href="/price/">
        <div class="logo"><img src="/images/logo.png"></div>
        <div class="logoText">Title</div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="about">
      About
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `float` with flexbox, use `justify-content` and `align-items` instead. `float` should only be used for images in a text paragraph, nothing else.

Also, there are many options to align your content like that, but most of them only exist because `flex` wasn't always a thing, and the old ways are usually extremely hacky. `grid` and `flex` are the modern ways for CSS layouting.

Example: (you can use `justify-content: space-between;` on the container to achieve the desired alignment, or experiment with `margin-right: auto` and `margin-left: auto`)

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#moveItem {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.85;
    filter: alpha(opacity=85); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

body, html{
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    overflow-y: hidden;
    background: black;
}

#navigator {

    z-index: 2;

    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;     /* center items vertically, in this case */
    justify-content: space-between;



}

#navIcon{
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor:pointer;


}
.about {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#navigator a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.logo {
    display: inline;
}

.logo img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
}

.logoheader{
    background:  rgba(0, 0, 0,  0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.logoText {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin-left: -12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigator">
    <div id="navIcon" onclick="openNav()"> &#9776;</div>

    <div class="logoheader">
      <a href="/price/">
        <div class="logo"><img src="/images/logo.png"></div>
        <div class="logoText">Title</div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="about">
      About
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```